# Inline execution of an anonymous function returned by a method: $obj->method()()

Tags: php, functional-programming, inline, anonymous-function

When a method returns a function, it can be called like so:

```
class AClass {
    public function getFnc() {
        $f = function() {
            echo "hello from a function";
        };
        return $f;
    }
}
```

On the calling side we can do:

```
$c = new AClass();
$f = $c->getFnc();
$f();
```

The output is `hello from a function` as excpected.

Writing the call inline doesn't compile:

```
$c->getFnc()();
```

How can this be written inline(ish) possibly with some casting? I am looking for an elegant way from the caller point of view.

In maths, stuff is evaluated in situ:

```
(3 + 2)(5 + 1)
(5)(6)
30
```

instead of introducing a unnecessary variable f1:

```
f1 = (3 + 2)
f1(5 + 1)
```

...

Comment: Can you explain what your actual goal is, because right now this just seems to be adding additional complexity for no reason. What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: return `$f()` instead of return $f

Comment: @Nouphal.M: Return f() would evaluate f and return the result. That would "inline" the function on the callee side and a string is returned in the example.

Comment: @FDL: I would like to have FUNctions as return values and evaluate them :-)

Comment: *"I am looking for an elegant way"* Sorry, wrong language. ;-) But seriously now, `call_user_func` is the best you can do. Until 5.4 you couldn't even index into a returned array in situ.

Comment: We already did this in perl in the 90ties `$f->foo()->()`

Comment: @Jon: Clean code can usually be enhanced more easily. Plus it's more fun to work with :-9

Comment: @raoulsson: no disagreement there. It's just that PHP has historically had ridiculous shortcomings like the one shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can be treated as a callback function so `call_user_func()` will work to invoke the returned function. You can call the function like so...

https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func

```
class AClass {
    public function getFnc() {
        $f = function() {
            echo "hello from a function";
        };
        return $f;
    }
}

$c = new AClass();
call_user_func($c->getFnc());
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and be sure about the version of your PHP : 
[Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: This answer should be converted to a comment under the question.  Link dropping is not much of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

php version 4.4 fails

php version 5.6 does `$f()` but fails at `$f()()`

php versions higher than 5.6 do both, so today, can say that these code pieces work fine..